# How to make array union with types used to make an array adhere to all the unions in the type

Tags: typescript

I have the followings issue I have a union type that i want to leverage to be used to to make a array adhere to all the included unions inside the type, in the flowing example the issue is that if you remove an item you still won't get any error, this cost me a decent bug since one array had a missing item but the union didn't see a missing element in it. and i don't make a specific type due to clean code issues.

```js
type AllTypes = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd';

// Array
const allTypesArray : AllTypes[] =  ['a','b','c','d']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAKuCBnKBeKByAhtqAHxwCMDjsBjcnAE2wG4AoJgeldgCdPcQnKA9gDtUwKLgTJIqGN15QAXLEkpUAbQC6mKFDV5sAGmxkj1I-Q1A)